# errors with gdalUtils::gdaltransform inside R (status 1, NAs)

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, r

I am using rgdal and gdalUtils in R and I am having problems with gdaltransform (which takes a 2 column matrix of coordinates and performs a transformation to a new CRS, from a given CRS) - this is [an R wrapper](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdalUtils/versions/2.0.1.7/topics/gdaltransform) for the [GDAL function](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html).

However I am having no luck in getting gdaltransform to run:

(R 3.4.4 64-bit, RStudio 1.0.153, Windows 10, packages = rgdal_1.2-16, gdalUtils_2.0.1.7, rgeos_0.3-26, gdal installed via OSGeo4W, GDAL_PATH set to C:\OSGeo4W64\bin)

```
# example taken from ?gdaltransform
# create points, check gdal installation and run function

gdal_setInstallation()
valid_install <- !is.null(getOption("gdalUtils_gdalPath"))
if(valid_install)
{
pts <- matrix(c(177502,311865,177503,311866),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
gdaltransform(s_srs="EPSG:28992",t_srs="EPSG:31370",coords=pts,verbose=TRUE)
}

Checking gdal_installation...
Scanning for GDAL installations...
Checking Sys.which...
GDAL version 2.2.1
GDAL command being used: "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdaltransform.exe" -s_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:27700"   < C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4SWk5F\file16004a1a1ef6
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA
[7,]   NA   NA   NA
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdaltransform.exe" -s_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:27700"   < C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4SWk5F\file16004a1a1ef6' had status 1 
2: In matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(cmd_output, split = " "))),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
3: In matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(cmd_output, split = " "))),  :
  data length [19] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [7]
```